# Content security policy to be added in vuejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, iis

I'm trying to add meta tag in (vue js /node.js) for content security policy header using the following tag but doesnt seem to work, as I'm expecting it to be displayed under f12 developer tools / response header. I'm new to Vue.js so please help me out.

```
<meta
        http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
        content="default-src 'self' http://localhost:8080; img-src https://* http://localhost:8080 ; child-src 'none';"
/>
```

Please let me know what is the best way to add this header under response headers --Content security policy.

Answer (score 1):

The not-so-good approach is to set a CSP using a  tag (in the HTML document). So how to implement basic CSP in Vue.js?

To ensure that your server is providing the correct header on all responses, please open the js file containing your application server logic and append the following code:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Security-Policy', "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'"
  );
  
  next();
});
```

Don't panic if your site looks terrible after this, implementing a proper Content Security Policy requires a lot of testing and correcting.

For more details refer to this guide: [How to Enable Content Security
Policy in vuejs](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/vue-content-security-policy-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/).

Comment: Could you tell me where exactly I need to add the piece of code ? I have main.js, vuetify.config and .vue page . So basically I want to know the ‘app’ mentioned above is object of vue?, please let me know

Comment: The code snippet added above is a middleware function in Node.js that sets the Content Security Policy (CSP) header for the server response. Note that this code snippet is not used directly in the Vue.js frontend application, but is used in the Node.js backend application to send the CSP header to the browser.